# System property JBoss to spring config file

Tags: spring, properties, jboss, system

is it possible to get a System.property from a JBoss5 to spring session factory config file?
I have an xml file with specified properties in JBoss5/server/MyApp/deployers/myConfigFile.xml. Now i would like to get specified property to my sessionFactory.xml Spring config file. For example in myConfigFile.xml i will have

```
Show.sql=true
Format.sql=true
```

and in sessionFactory.xml

```
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${Show.sql}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${Format.sql}</prop>
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Use this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer

Comment: but how will i know package the file is placed in as it is not in any of my projects

Comment: Is that file on the app classpath?

Comment: it doesn't work if i put <value>classpath:myConfigFile.xml</value>

Comment: should i use classpath*:myConfigFile.xml if the file is being uploaded by JBoss?

Comment: My question was different: I was referring to application's classpath. You just put in your question a location on hard-drive. What does this location mean? It is static? It's on the application's classpath? What do you mean by "uploaded by JBoss"?

Comment: this location means that jboss's mbean is configured to read this file on startup and set system properties by key=values provided inside it